# Z-index Slider nested divs

Tags: html, css, revolution-slider

I've got a revolution slider with static layers. I want the static layer inbetween the background and the other layers. This is a prox of the code:

```
<ul class="slides">
   <li class="slide"> // position: absolute;
     <img src="bg.png"> // z-index: 10;
     <div class="caption">text</div> // z-index: 30;
   </li>
</ul>
<div class="static-layers"> // z-index: 15;
   <div class="static layer"> // z-index:  20;
      <img src="staticbg.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

I can't get it to work. Anyone got any tips ?

Comment: Did you apply the position property to the elements with a z-index? It only works when for example absolute or relative are applied.

Comment: All either relative or absolute indeed. When I remove absolute from .slide it does work.

Comment: Did you perhaps give the `.slide` class a `z-index` as well? In that case the z-index is applied to its contents making it impossible to slide anything in between. Without a z-index on that class I could get this to work.

Comment: Without this z-index it does work, however revolution slider generates this z-index. Any way to get it to work with this z-index ?

Answer (score 1):

Override `z-index` on the `.slide` class setting it to its default value:

```
.slide {
   z-index: initial;
}
```

(If `z-index` is set inline on the .slide element add `!important`.)